# what is the syntax error in this code in python?

Tags: python, code-formatting

I'm new in programming and in python and i was watching a lecture and i wanted to create a simple functions like the lecturer do in the video , so i design 3 functions , addition , mean , mean_Addition as show below , addition is just add 2 numbers and mean function calculate the mean of the two numbers the mean_Addition adds the mean and the addition of two numbers

i writed the code and run the program but it had told me that there is some syntax error , i checked it over and over again but i can't decide what is the wrong

the code of my simple programme is :

```
def addition(float1,float2):
     '''(float,float)-> float

return the addition of float1 and float2 .

>>> addition(2,3)
5.0
>>>addition(4,6)
10.0 '''
     return float1+float2


def mean(x , y ):
    '''
(number,number)-> float
return the mean of two numbers , x and y .
>>> mean(2,4)
 3.0
>>> mean(9,2)
5.5
 '''
    return  addition(x,y)/ 2



def Mean_Addition(t,s):
'''
(float,float)->float
return the mean of the two numbers plus the addition of the two numbers
>>> Mean_Addition(1,2)
4.5
>>> Mean_Addition(4,5)
13.5
'''
    return addition(t,s) + mean(t,s)
```

one thing i want to mention is that the error is in the third function Mean_Addition because when i deleted this part it worked well !

the problem is , when I choose run modulo it says "expected an indented block"

so what is the syntax error which i have made ?

Thanks.

---

note : for those who will explore this question in the future , the syntax error which i made ( i learned this from the answer ) is i wrote

```
def Mean_Addition(t,s):
'''
(float,float)->float
```

but we shouldn't put " ''' " under "def" , we should make a space under "def"
so the right code is

```
def Mean_Addition(t,s):
    '''
(float,float)->float
```

Comment: The docstring isn't indented

Comment: and you have an extra " at the end

Comment: And you didn't show us the full traceback from your error.

Comment: and you spelled "please" incorrectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def addition(float1,float2):
     """
     (float,float)-> float
     return the addition of float1 and float2 .
     >>> addition(2,3)
     5.0
     >>>addition(4,6)
     10.0 
     """
     return float1+float2


def mean(x , y ):
    """
    (number,number)-> float
    return the mean of two numbers , x and y .
    >>> mean(2,4)
    3.0
    >>> mean(9,2)
    5.5
    """
    return  addition(x,y)/ 2



def Mean_Addition(t,s):
    """ <----- the error was here
    (float,float)->float
    return the mean of the two numbers plus the addition of the two numbers
    >>> Mean_Addition(1,2)
    4.5
    >>> Mean_Addition(4,5)
    13.5
    """
    return addition(t,s) + mean(t,s)
```

Comment: where was the error ? what is the phrase which had the error ?

Comment: remember in python indentation has meaning.  Compare the line marked carefully.